# Review of simple gallery method

Tags: asp.net

I wanted to get a code review of my methods for creating a simple list/gallery display in ASP.NET. I am looking for specific ideas on how I might approach this same task differently. My goals are simplicity, rapid development, and ease-of-use.

The task: Create a simple image list view (gallery) for a folder in ASP.NET web forms.

How I Did It:
I created the image controls on the fly and add them to a placeholder template. I added line breaks using literals controls too. Finally, I add a query string to the page for the "paging".

What other ways would one recommend to do this? I had considered to use a grid or listview. My goal was to do this really quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Create a simple image list view (gallery) for a folder in ASP.NET web forms.

I suggest you take a look at this simple httphandler solution: http://photohandler.codeplex.com/. Here are some samples:

http://i3.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=PhotoHandler&DownloadId=14384

http://i3.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=PhotoHandler&DownloadId=14386

Grz, Kris.